Understanding the data leakage article on The ICML 2013 Whale Challenge - Right Whale Redux
I came across this article while trying to understand more about data leakage.
https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/the-icml-2013-whale-challenge-right-whale-redux/discussion/4865
Though really good points are highlighted here,  I still could not understand where is the data leak happening here. Needed some help in knowing how this article identifies data leakage?
